# How to programmatically delete the folder or subfolder from Sharepoint server using c#

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, development

I want to delete some folders from my server. How I can programmatically delete the folder.
So I tried this but it didn't help:

```
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(ClientContext.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPFolderCollection folders = web.Folders["TestList"].SubFolders;
                    foreach (SPFolder folder in folders)
                    {
                        if (folder.Name == "MyDeleteFolders")
                        {
                            web.Folders["TestList"].SubFolders.Delete(folder.Url);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Getting any error or can't find folders?

Comment: Maybe you just need web.Update(). And try using folder.Delete() inside of your foreach cycle (you'll need web.Update() this case too).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `FolderName` instead of `FolderURL` to be like this

```
if (folder.Name == "MyDeleteFolders")
{
 web.Folders["TestList"].SubFolders.Delete(folder.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void DeleteDirectory(string path)
{
    DeleteDirectory(path, false);
}

public static void DeleteDirectory(string path, bool recursive)
{
    // Delete all files and sub-folders?
    if (recursive)
    {
        // Yep... Let's do this
        var subfolders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        foreach (var s in subfolders)
        {
            DeleteDirectory(s, recursive);
        }
    }

    // Get all files of the folder
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    foreach (var f in files)
    {
        // Get the attributes of the file
        var attr = File.GetAttributes(f);

        // Is this file marked as 'read-only'?
        if ((attr & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        {
            // Yes... Remove the 'read-only' attribute, then
            File.SetAttributes(f, attr ^ FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
        }

        // Delete the file
        File.Delete(f);
    }

    // When we get here, all the files of the folder were
    // already deleted, so we just delete the empty folder
    Directory.Delete(path);
}
```